# Client and server-side validation with RESTful APIs

Tags: api, validation, rest

Let's assume I have a `POST /orders` operation that takes as input a collection of order items. An order can't contain more than 50 items, but where do I perform this validation?

Validating the order size in both the client and the server would be redundant, and increase the maintenance cost if I decide to change the order size limit,.

Validating it only in the server would prevent clients from "failing fast" (i.e., you add a thousand items to the order and is informed of the limit only when completing it).

I'm assuming client-only validation is not an option, as the API may have other clients.

The problem gets more complicated if I have dynamic validation rules. Suppose retail customers can have orders 50 items, but wholesale customers can have 500 items in their orders. Should the API expose an operation so clients can fetch the current validation rules?

Comment: You have to validate on the server, as you simply cannot trust clients. You want to validate client side to reduce the work the server has to do. Managing these things can be tedious yes, perhaps expose via the REST API the validation **values**, leave it to clients to use that information to improve the clients experience (ie, inform them before submitting that they have ordered too many items)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do both, but differently.

To guarantee valid operations, all critical validation must happen on the server/web service side. The client side UI is just that - a user interface to make interacting with the web service convenient for a person. Once the web service is stable and secure, create a default method to pass web service errors through the client to the user. After that, features in the UI layer are usability issues and should be based on testing (even if that is informal testing by watching over a user's shoulder or listening to feedback.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what was said [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044285).

Although, I think if you can predict almost every situation a user may come into, you could also create client-side validation.

As per your example about wholesale/retail, you could first create a drop-down that asks the client to choose whether they're wholesale or retail and then apply the 500/50 rule to the input box based on the first option.

The obvious problem comes in the fact that if your API is released to other developers, they may not be aware of the 50/500 rule and that is where I agree with the previous answer about critical validation happening on the server. If you're building the API for your own use then you could go either way because you're aware of the input restrictions. It will also save quite a bit on server-costs if the app is very big (validation on the server will be taxing).